# ASP.NET Core Razor Pages and localisation

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I was wondering if there is a way in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages to set the culture for a folder?  For example:

```
{Project}
Pages
  en
  fr
```

Where all pages in the en folder are english and all folders in the fr folder are French.  I know I can set it at the PageModel level, but I'd prefer to not have to make maintenance of the site harder than it needs to be

Comment: So you essentialy want to do copy&paste with just some labels changing? Why aren't you just translated labels?

Comment: This is for a web site, I want to lay the web site out similarly to https://www.nespresso.com.  The content on the page will eventually be passed in via a headless CMS, but for now I was thinking of just using a user control for each language as the content will change regularly.  Marketing are also looking at web site personalisation so a german translated site "could" end up with different content to the english version